# display images inline for slideshow

Tags: html, css, slider, flexbox

I am trying to create a carousel flexbox, I am facing the problem of displaying the items inside the container!

I want the item list to be displayed inline and go off/hide behind the container. In other words, I don't want it to make another row. More like a slider.

Here is what I did so far.

```css
.carousel-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  margin:40px 20px;
  
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  width:auto;
  
  border: 1px solid red;
  
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.carousel-item {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.item {
  border: 0.5px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
  display: inline-flex;
  
  width: 10%;
}

.item > a {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.prev-button, .next-button {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.navigation {
  height:120px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.next-button:hover, .prev-button:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.navigation:active {
  color: white;
}

.next-button {
  right:0;
}

.prev-button {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-container">
  <a class="prev-button navigation" href="#"><</a>
  &nbsp;
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <li class="item"><a href="#"> TESTING </a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#"> TESTING </a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#"> TESTING </a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#"> TESTING </a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#"> TESTING </a></li>
    
    <li class="item"><a href="#"> TESTING </a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#"> TESTING </a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#"> TESTING </a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#"> TESTING </a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#"> TESTING </a></li>
  </div>
  &nbsp;
  <a class="next-button navigation" href="#">></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Did it solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a particular width and height to `carousel-container` and make it overflow hidden. Then the `carousel-item` which has slide items in it. Assign it at least wider width than parent div (or use jquery to assign width dynamically). Because the parent has a shorter width and overflow hidden it will show those items which it can. Don't forget to make `li` display: inline;

```css
.carousel-container {
  width: 360px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slidescontainer {
  width: 840px;
  height: 200px;
}

.carousel-item li {
  display: inline;
}
```

See the source of the second slider here: https://umair-ameen.github.io/zoom-slider/

Comment: Alright, It gave me a little understanding of the sizes, but somehow I am trying to display 4-5 images at a time, and when you click the arrow it scrolls to the other 5 images

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle so I can make changes in your code?

Comment: Let me see it :)

Comment: Why are you making it a flex div? and havn't you written any jquery?

Comment: Not yet, I'm trying to make the css first, then add the click events

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149317/discussion-between-robert-williams-and-sora-keyheart).